How much influence do the below 3 SCOTUS precedents have for Trump voiding birthright citizenship?
President Elect Trump has said he wanted to void birthright citizenship as a means to curb illegal immigration to the USA.
The 14th amendment of the Constitution guarantees that "all people born in the US and subject to the jurisdiction thereof are citizens of the US and of their state of residence" The prevailing legal consensus is that birthright citizenship can only be ended via a constitutional amendment, not executive action/ executive order.
Supreme Court of the United States has ruled in the below trifecta of cases that essentially removed or severely limited the ability of Congress to remove citizenship from anyone. Don't consider precedent from Wong Kim Ark ruling.

Trop v. Dulles (1958) - Congress lacks authority to strip citizenship as a means of criminal punishment

Afroyim v. Rusk (1967) - Congress may not strip citizenship from someone involuntarily

Vance v. Terrazas (1980) - Complement to Afroyim ruling that citizenship can only be relinquished upon showing of purposeful intent.


To what degree do these 3 precedents constrain what Trump can do to annul birthright citizenship

The last I heard, which was a couple of weeks ago, the plan was to change the interpretation of the 14th amendment and the Immigration and Nationality Act only with respect to future births, not to attempt to apply this interpretation to anyone born beforehand.  Has this changed recently?  (If not then these cases are probably not among the most relevant.)

Such would be ex post facto and hence unconstitutional , no?

As the answer explains, if the courts agree that the interpretation was wrong all along then it's not an ex-post-facto law and not necessarily unconstitutional.  It would be manifestly unjust, of course, so it's not likely to happen, but it isn't strictly speaking prohibited by the constitution.

@phoog Why assume that manifestly unjust things are unlikely to happen in today's world?

@phoog why is it manifestly unjust to rectify an (alleged) mistake?

@RonJohn suppose you're 75 years old, you've never been outside the US, you have no nationality other than US, and then the US tells you you're not a US citizen after all.  Seems mighty unjust to me.

@phoog it seems mighty impractical to me; where's he going to go (given that no other country has or had him registered as a citizen)?  To the point, though: proper implementation of the law is considered "justice".

@RonJohn justice has way too many definitions and "unjust law" is not something unheard of.

Both the Citizenship Clause of the 14th Amendment, and section 301(a) of the Immigration and Nationality Act (8 USC 1401(a)) grant citizenship to people born in the United States only if they were born "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" (i.e. of the United States). If someone were to successfully argue that birthright citizenship does not apply to a certain group of people, because they were not born "subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]" within the meaning of both the Citizenship Clause of the 14th Amendment, and the Immigration and Nationality Act, and that we have been interpreting it wrong all along, then presumably the decision can retroactively apply to people who were already born, because this is an interpretation of the Constitution and laws that already existed at the time of their birth. The people would be deemed to have never been US citizens in the first place, and any documents verifying citizenship they may have been issued would be deemed to have been issued "in error". (This is similar to how, if someone's naturalization is later found to have been fraudulent, or when someone born in the US is later found to have been born to a diplomat like Hoda Muthana, they are legally considered to have never been US citizens at all, even if they have previously been issued US passports.) In this case, since they are considered to have never been citizens, there is no "loss of citizenship", and the Supreme Court precedents on loss of US citizenship do not apply.
If the court were to hypothetically limit its decision to apply prospectively to people born after the decision, then I believe that the precedents against loss of US citizenship would protect people born before the decision from having their citizenship involuntarily taken away by a future Act of Congress or the Executive Branch, because they would be considered to have been "born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof" within the meaning of the Citizenship Clause of the 14th Amendment. (At least those people who were born in the 50 states or DC. People born in unincorporated territories might not be covered.)
Another possibility is the court might rule that a certain group of people were not born "subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]" for the purposes of the 14th Amendment and the Immigration and Nationality Act, and this applies to people who were already born, but as an interim remedy, in light of longstanding interpretation, allow people who were already born to keep their citizenship, as if provided by statute, unless and until Congress decides otherwise. Basically, this would remove the Constitutional protection against a future Act of Congress removing their citizenship involuntarily, because the US Supreme Court clarified in Rogers v. Bellei (1971) that precedents on loss of US citizenship like Afroyim v. Rusk (1967) only apply to those who were "born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof" within the meaning of the Citizenship Clause of the 14th Amendment. (Bellei was a US citizen from birth, born abroad, and therefore was not "born or naturalized in the United States". His citizenship was only granted by an Act of Congress, and the court ruled in Rogers v. Bellei that it was constitutional for Congress to take away his citizenship involuntarily, under certain circumstances.)
Another case I can imagine is if the court rules that a certain group of people were not born "subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]" for the purposes of the 14th Amendment and the Immigration and Nationality Act, and this applies to people who were already born, but Congress subsequently enacts a law to grant citizenship back to some or all of this group of people. (This would be similar to how Congress granted US citizenship to Native Americans born on reservations with the Indian Citizenship Act of 1924, after the US Supreme Court ruled in Elk v. Wilkins (1884) that they were not born "subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]".) As above, whether the Constitutional protection against involuntarily loss of citizenship applies depends on whether they were "born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof". To the extent that this law applies to grant citizenship at birth to people born after the law takes effect, the court clearly said they were "not subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]" at birth, so they would not be protected against a future law that took away their citizenship involuntarily. To the extent that this law applies to grant citizenship to people who were born before the law took effect, the granting of citizenship is considered naturalization, but there are still of the questions of 1) whether they were "in the United States" when this naturalization happens (i.e. in the 50 states or DC; unincorporated territories probably don't count), and 2) whether this group of people are considered to be "subject to the jurisdiction [of the United States]" when they are naturalized, if they were not subject to its jurisdiction at birth. I have no idea how the court would rule on this second question.

The threshold date would have to be the date of the administration's change in policy, not of the court decision; otherwise, the court would have to say "plaintiff Baby X is a citizen because we hadn't decided get, but future similarly situated babies will not be."

How much influence do you see Plyler v. Doe case play?

@phoog: I think the administration would have to argue that the birthright citizenship was never there under existing law, and not something that changed from the date of their action, because the administration has no power to "change policy" on this.

@phoog: There is precedent for the court making a citizenship law change "prospectively" (interpreted as starting from the date of the decision), in Sessions v. Morales-Santana (2017), although the differences are that that case only involved statute (the court ordered an interim remedy while waiting for Congress to amend the statute), did not involve a change in administration policy, and the change that the court ordered did not involve the class of the plaintiff (plaintiff was born out of wedlock to US father, but court ordered a change for people born out of wedlock to US mother).

"I think the administration would have to argue...": My understanding is that the incoming administration plans to adopt the position that the "subject to the jurisdiction" clause does not apply to people who are not legally in the country (and possibly to some or all classes of nonimmigrants). This will be a change in policy. I have also read that they aren't planning to try to apply this different interpretation to people who were born before the change in policy (presumably because they think that this would be more likely to succeed than trying include people who are already alive).

@phoog: But if the court decides that the clause does not apply to certain people, this should be true before or after the administration's actions (unless the court limits its decision to prospective cases like in Sessions v. Morales-Santana). The administration can't choose to have people born before their action still have citizenship, because that would effectively mean granting citizenship to people who (according to this hypothetical court ruling) were not granted citizenship by the Constitution or statute, and the administration has no power to grant citizenship unilaterally like that.

@phoog: Or do you mean that the court will rule that the administration's action changed the meaning of "subject to the jurisdiction thereof" from that date onwards? But it would be weird to hold that the Executive Branch has the power to unilaterally change the meaning of terms in the Constitution and statute, especially since the end of Chevron deference.

@user102008, I highly doubt your second interpretation of Phoog's answer will fly. Executive branch lacks the power to unilaterally modify the Constitution other than following the process for amendments laid out on the Constitution itself

@Anthony While the 2nd Amendment only states "Arms", the actual class of that you are allowed to own is limited or highly regulated.  But there was no change made to the constitution.  IMHO there may be loop holes (similar to how the 2nd is interpreted) that are sufficient for weasel words to provide the restrictions that the Trump administration wants.

The historical reason for the citizenship clause of the 14th Amendment was to complement the freedom clause of the 13th Amendment, and give the freed slaves full citizenship. I doubt that it was intended to be prospective, but it's poorly written, and the Supreme Court later decided that it made anyone born in the US a citizen. The question is whether this was an error. Applying the "Law of Unintended Consequences" to the Constitution is very, very hard.

The last paragraph doesn't make any sense. If Congress passes a law to collectively naturalize a group of people who live in the US, then those people are "naturalized in the United States" and they are subject to its jurisdiction just as much as any other people who were naturalized in the United States.

@Brian: Good point. I have made some updates

Re the "subject to its jurisdiction" requirement, it's hard to see how a court could come to the conclusion that anyone naturalized in the United States could be not subject to its jurisdiction. The Supreme Court applied the 14th Amendment in Afroyim v. Rusk without even stopping to ask the question of whether Afroyim, a naturalized citizen, was actually subject to US jurisdiction. I take this as an indication that it was too obvious to even think about.
